# How to Compile and Install Remmina From GIT Repository for Ubuntu (KDE)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, git, kde

Gentlemen,

I would like to compile a version of Remmina directly from the GIT repository, because I need to apply a patch to fix a problem.

With the command sequence below I can compile it and install it, but the application not recognizing the RDP plugin ("Protocol plugin RDP is not installed.").

My distribution is the Linux Mint KDE 16 (Ubuntu based).

Can anyone help me with this?

```
sudo su

apt-get install git
apt-get -y install cmake

git clone https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP.git
cd FreeRDP
mkdir build

cmake --build=build .
make
make install

git clone https://gist.github.com/5214302.git
git clone https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina.git
cd Remmina
patch -p1 < '/home/brlight/5214302/0001-Don-t-seg-fault-if-no-perms-to-read-.remmina-files-o.patch'
apt-get -y install libgtk-3-dev libgcrypt11-dev libssh-dev libvte-2.90-dev libxkbfile-dev libfreerdp-dev libtelepathy-glib-dev libjpeg-dev libgnutls-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libavahi-ui-gtk3-dev libvncserver-dev libappindicator3-dev intltool
mkdir build

cmake --build=build .
make
make install
```

Comment: Please post the exact error messages you are getting.

Comment: Marius, the output is huge! =/

Answer (score 3):

The Remmina developers are publishing a snap of remmina, and also publish nightly builds to the edge channel of the snap store. So if you want to track git master, you no longer have to compile from source.

### Installing Remmina on Ubuntu or Linux Mint

You can install the Remmina snap on Ubuntu 14.04 or newer and Linux Mint 17.x or newer.

`sudo apt install snapd
sudp snap install remmina`

### Getting edge builds of Remmina

Once you have the snap of Remmina installed you can switch to the edge channel to subscribe to the nighlty builds.

`sudo snap refresh remmina --edge`

Should you ever want to switch back to the stable release you can use the same snap refresh command above and simply change `--edge` for `--stable`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Any chance FreeRDP and Remmina are out of step? Perhaps try FreeRDP 1.1 with Remmina Master?</strike> Tried it. Didn't work. I've tried:

- purging all apt packages for freerdp, libfreerdp, xfreerdp, remmina, remmina-plugins, etc.
- as above, but purging all remaining shared objects
- using sudo checkinstall instead of sudo make install

Same every time. It's not a system thing, there's a problem in the code - I've contributed to your bug report on GitHub.

If you think your output is too large, consider a pastebin link, so we can see it?

**I've been able to get a solution, but it requires manual intevention.
After the cmake line, edit Remmina-master/remmina-plugins/rdp/cmake_install.cmake and remove the RPATH_REMOVE instruction across lines 53 and 54.**

It's not tidy, but it does get RDP running again.

Answer (score 0):

The rdp plugin compiled fine after having installed freerdp from git:
https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation

After compiling and installing remmina I had to add the following lines to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/freerdp.conf`:

```
/usr/local/lib/freerdp
/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Now remmina can load the rdp plugin because it can find `libfreerdp-core.so`.